# Configure Wacom Intuos S Pen (CH480L)

Tags: 14.04, wacom, input, graphics-tablet, configure

Hello My problem is this: I can not configure the 4 physical buttons tablet. I searched a lot but can not find a post that speak clearly about it.
I tried using "xsetwacom" but to enter "button Stylus xsetwacom set 8 control" appears "Can not find device 'Stylus'."
Another thing. I do not know the numbers of the buttons. I used the number "8" at random.
I am new to Linux. I use Ubuntu 14.04. The tablet is Wacom Intuos Small Pen (only, not touch).

PD: Sorry, my English is not fluent. I speak Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/bugs/244/ and in particular the script attached to the fifth comment.